# Dark mode through JS on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, darkmode

I have been trying to add dark mode on a practice webpage, it works to change the body background color, but isn't working on the buttons, the code is:

the code is not working on the .icons CSS class, it comes up in chrome, but doesn't function,

explanation is highly appreciated.

Thank You

```js
document.querySelector(".slider-button").addEventListener("input", function(){
  document.querySelector("#data-left").innerHTML = this.value;
})

document.querySelector(".slider-button").addEventListener("input", function(){
  document.querySelector(".gb-left").innerHTML = 1000-this.value;
})

document.querySelector(".button-color-mode").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.body.classList.toggle("darkmode");
  document.querySelector(".icons").classList.toggle("darkmode");
})
```

```css
body {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: hsl(229, 57%, 11%);
  background-image: url("images/bg-desktop.png");
  background-position: center 400px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.button-color-mode{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.darkmode{
  background-color: white;
}

.icons {
  background-color: hsl(229, 57%, 11%);
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Fylo Data Storage</title>
</head>

<body>
      <button class="icons" type="button"><img src="images/icon-document.svg" alt="" name="button"></button>
      <button class="icons" type="button"><img src="images/icon-folder.svg" alt="" name="button"></button>
      <button class="icons" type="button"><img src="images/icon-upload.svg" alt="" name="button"></button>
</html>
```

Comment: Your example is missing the `slider-button` and `button-color-mode` elements. Also, `querySelector` returns a single element. You have three buttons with the class `icons` so you would need to use `querySelectorAll` and loop through the returned collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CSS the order in which selectors are defined matters. When a rule (e.g. `background-color`) is defined in multiple selectors of the same specificity the one defined last will overwrite any previous definition.

In this case `.icons { background-color: ... }` is defined *after* `.darkmode { background-color: ... }`, therefore `.icons` "wins" even if the `darkmode` class is set as well.

In other words: Move the `.darkmode`-block below the `.icons`-block.

Comment: Thank You for the help, I have just started learning from Udemy.com.
Coding is fun!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery just to implement this basic feature.

This method uses a button to manually toggle between light (default) and dark modes.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Dark Mode</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Dark mode demo</h1>
        <button onclick="switch_mode()">Dark</button>
        <p> 
           Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat odio repellendus neque illum explicabo architecto minima eligendi expedita
        </p>     
</body>
</html>
```

```
<style>
        html {font-size: 100%;}

        body {
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.75;
            color: #3f0d7d;
        }

        .dark-mode {
            background: #3e3939;
            color: white;
        }

</style>
```

The following js script toggles dark mode class to the body element.

```
<script>
    //this function is called when the button is clicked
    function switch_mode(){
        const element = document.body;
        element.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
    }
</script>
```

It has been discussed in detail [here](https://github.com/avecNava/dark-mode)